# How to Update my Ruby on Rails production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-ec2, capistrano, ubuntu-18.04

Please help! I've successfully launched a Ruby on Rails BE server (a Postgres DB via an Amazon EC2 Instance) to production using Capistrano.

Now I've just updated my rails app for the first time on my local machine and pushed these updates to my git repo, yet I'm not seeing these updates in production.

I expected my pushed git updates to reach my instance. I then attempted to re-deploy my server but that didn't work either.

How do I update my production application?

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration!

Comment: Did you do a cap deploy?  You stated that you pushed to git, but the next step after that is usually something along the lines of `cap production deploy` or whatever the ENV is called.  What commands have you run since pushing to git?  Can you edit the question and add those in?

Comment: @RockwellRice I initially pushed to git, then ran `cap production deploy` and it ran successfully. I then made updates a few days later and pushed those updates to git. Should I be running `cap production deploy` again? And every time after pushing new updates to git?

Comment: Yes that command pushes the updated code to production.  So every time you push to git and want it to go live on production, you then have to then deploy using capistrano.

Comment: Got it thank you for your help!